# Can I somehow partially implement a bunch of generics of a single class

Tags: java, generics

Can I somehow partially implement a bunch of generics of a single class? What I would like to achieve is that I can accept a generic only when somone really relies on that type. See the following foo/bar example for a demonstration purpose of what I am looking for:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Sample {
    public static abstract class ASomeFunc<AK, AV, PK, PV> {

        public void forwardTo(ASomeFunc<?, ?, PK, PV> lala) {

        }

        // EDIT 1:
        // we do some logic here and then pass a map entry to an actual implementation
        // but somethimes I do not care what the key is I am just interested in what the value is
        // public abstract Map.Entry<PK, PV> compute(Map.Entry<AK, AV> data);
    }

    public static class SomeFunc2 extends ASomeFunc<Date, String, Number, Number> {

    }


    // what I would like to do:
    // public static class SomeOtherFunc extends ASomeFunc<?, Number, ?, Number> {
    // but I ony can:
    public static class SomeOtherFunc extends ASomeFunc<Object, Number, Object, Number> {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // but this now clashes ... sinc object is explicitly defined
        new SomeFunc2().forwardTo(new SomeOtherFunc());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of 'template specialization' in C++? If positive, prepare to be disappointed. Search for "type erasure Java  generics"

Comment: Why would a subclass not rely on that type? Might the abstract class be too specialised?

Comment: Actually it doesn't compile because according to `forwardTo`  and the type of `SomeFunc2`, `SomeOtherFunc` is expected to be of type `ASomeFunc<?, ?, Number, Number>` while its 2 last parameter types are `Object` and `Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` would not work either, the second to last type argument would have to be exactly `Number` (since generics are invariant).

You might be able to get around it with some unchecked casts (an ugly solution). Or if, `PK` is a consumer type, use:

```
forwardTo(ASomeFunc<?, ?, ? super PK, PV> lala)
```

Which will also make your example compile. (See also, [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super))

But what your case implies is that you're only implementing part of the interface of `ASomeFunc` with your subclass.

In that case you should really try to split up the interface of `ASomeFunc` so that each subclass can choose exactly what they need to implement, but nothing more.

Comment: yes I am only implementing one opart of an interface. Sadly this interface operates on a `Map.Entry<K,V>` but somethimes i just do not care about the key but just consume the value. See my edit in the code snipped.